# How to take screenshot of whole screen using wxpython

Tags: python, opencv, wxpython

I'm setting up an imageprocessing tool which input should be a screenshot.

The wx python screenshot function works in the aspect that the dimensions are correct but the image is zoomed and therefore not the whole screen is captured.

```
def taking_screenshot():
    screen = wx.ScreenDC()
    size=screen.GetSize()
    bmp = wx.Bitmap(size[0],size[1])
    mem=wx.MemoryDC(bmp)
    mem.Blit(0,0,size[0],size[1],screen,0,0)
    del mem
    bmp.SaveFile('screenshot_for_working.PNG',wx.BITMAP_TYPE_PNG)
   ('window',cv2.imread('screenshot_for_working.PNG') )
```

The imagewindow that is opened is covering the whole put the actual picture is zoomed and therefore shows only partly the screen

Comment: windows or linux? python and wx version? Post screenshot and keep private information blurred.

Answer (score 0):

Here some minor adjustment that should do the trick. Use wording like `width` and `height` so you can track which values go where.

At the `print (width, height)` you can compare with DisplaySize and if not correct you should define width/height yourself.

```py
def taking_screenshot():
    screen = wx.ScreenDC()
    size=screen.GetSize()

    print (wx.DisplaySize())                # debugging: see if pixel values are okay.

    width = size[0]
    height = size[1]

    print (width, height)                    # compare with above values.

    bmp = wx.EmptyBitmap(width,height)       # use EmptyBitmap here instead of wx.Bitmap.
    mem=wx.MemoryDC(bmp)
    mem.SelectObject(bmp)                   # tell mem to use the actual bitmap
    mem.Blit(0,0,width, height,screen,0,0)
    del mem
    bmp.SaveFile('screenshot_for_working.PNG',wx.BITMAP_TYPE_PNG)
   ('window', cv2.imread('screenshot_for_working.PNG') )
```

You can also check here: https://github.com/ponty/pyscreenshot for another tool to "screenshot".

Answer (score 0):

thank you very much for your idea. I figured it out. In my basic screensetting the everything made bigger zoom was set to 150%. Thanks anyway.